# React.js: How to close headlessui Disclosure modal from code?

Tags: reactjs

I encountered an issue  trying to close the `headlessui Disclosure modal` inside the panel.
My goal is to have a button inside the panel which can close the modal.

The way I tried to solve this problem is doing it manually using `useRef`, but it works partially. 
After opening the `panel`  for the first time, you can close the `modal` but if you try to open it again, it doesn't work. 
Can't figure out how to solve this issue. 
Any help will be appreciated.
[Here is the codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/headlessui-v8sqz?file=/src/App.js:0-931)

And here is the code

```
import { Disclosure } from "@headlessui/react";
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
const App = () => {
  const [isClosed, setIsClosed] = useState(false);

  const modalRef = useRef(null);
  const hideModalHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    modalRef.current?.click();
    setIsClosed(!isClosed);
  };

  return (
    <Disclosure>
      {({ open }) => (
        <div ref={modalRef}>
          <Disclosure.Button>
            <span>modal</span>
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </Disclosure.Button>

          {!isClosed && (
            <Disclosure.Panel>
              <CloseIcon onClick={hideModalHandler} />
              <div>name</div>
            </Disclosure.Panel>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `headlessui Disclosure` but I see that the function `hideModalHandler` isn't actually hiding but toggling. Did you mean `setIsClosed(true)` instead of `setIsClosed(!isClosed)`?

Also, after a quick look at the documentation, have you tried using the [`close`](https://headlessui.dev/react/disclosure#closing-disclosures-manually) from the `headlessui Disclosure`? You don't need `useRef`

Comment: Hi @Imanpal Singh thanks for your answer. 
You are right, I don't need to toggle,  ' setIsClosed(true)' is enough.  
And  'close' from the headlessui Disclosure works fine react jsx. Thanks for the link. Even though it doesn't work with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Use the state, and wrap the disclosure button into a DIV
with onClick and some ID string to identify what disclosure must be open. Something like this (works for multiple disclosures):

```
const [keyOfOpenDisclosure, setKeyOfOpenDisclosure] = useState('')

const toggleDisclosure = (key: string) => {
    setKeyOfOpenDisclosure((prev) => (prev !== key ? key : ''))
}

...

<Disclosure>
    <div onClick={() => toggleDisclosure(someId)}>
        <Disclosure.Button>
            Text of disclosure button
        </Disclosure.Button>
    </div>
    <Transition
      show={someId === keyOfOpenDisclosure}
...
```